# How to use Rijndael algorithm with 256 long block size in dotnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core, rijndael, .net-core-2.1

I'm trying to encrypt a string with `RijndaelManaged` in order to send it to a third-party service. I've implemented the procedure in older versions of .Net framework (4.5, 4.6.x) like below:

```
RijndaelManaged rm= new RijndaelManaged();
rm.KeySize = 256;
rm.BlockSize = 256;//causes exception in dotnet core 2.1
rm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
rm.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(this.Key);
rm.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(this.IV);

var encrypt = rm.CreateEncryptor(rm.Key, rm.IV);
```

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=netcore-2.1#remarks), `RijndaelManaged` class can be used with `BlockSize = 256`. But, when the code is running in dotenet core 2.1, an exception thrown:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: BlockSize must be 128 in this implementation.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged.set_BlockSize(Int32 value)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Access-Denied's response, according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/Internal/Cryptography/RijndaelImplementation.cs), I've noticed that it may be a mistake in dotnet core documentation and I can't use a 256 long `BlockSize` with `RijndaelManaged` class. As I mentioned, encrypted data is going to be sent to a third-party service. I have to use Rijndael with a 32 long `IV`. How can I handle that?

Comment: Do you really need a block size different from 128? It's not linked to the key size. Key size 256 works perfectly with block size 128. If the encryption is supposed to be compatible with AES, the block size must be 128 and the key size either 128, 192 or 256.

Comment: @Codo Yes, I have to use 256 for block size. Encrypted data is going to sent to third-party service and I've got an `IV` from the third-party with 32 lengths.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: You want Rijndael with a 256-bit block size, but you use the variable name `aes` to hold it? If that isn't intentional obfuscation then you are confused.

Comment: It's not an intentional obfuscation, nor a confusion. I know what they are and their differences. I just copied the sample code the third-party company provided. But it's a good suggestion to change the names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best documentation is a source code. According to their [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/Internal/Cryptography/RijndaelImplementation.cs) only 128 is supported:

```
public override int BlockSize
{
    get { return _impl.BlockSize; }
    set
    {
        Debug.Assert(BlockSizeValue == 128);

        //Values which were legal in desktop RijndaelManaged but not here in this wrapper type
        if (value == 192 || value == 256)
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.Cryptography_Rijndael_BlockSize);

        // Any other invalid block size will get the normal "invalid block size" exception.
        if (value != 128)
            throw new CryptographicException(SR.Cryptography_Rijndael_BlockSize);
    }
}
```

Use BouncyCastle.NetCore. There is a code snippet available at the following [link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12064):

```
var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
var engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
var blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());
var keyParam = new KeyParameter(keyBytes);
var keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivStringBytes, 0, 32);

cipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIV);
var comparisonBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(cipherTextBytes.Length)];
var length = cipher.ProcessBytes(cipherTextBytes, comparisonBytes, 0);
cipher.DoFinal(comparisonBytes, length);
```

Comment: "Rijndael" as originally specified allowed various block sizes. It's when it was adopted *as* AES that the block size restriction was added in that incarnation. So you definitely shouldn't be able to find something claiming to implement AES that offers variable block sizes.

Comment: For anyone who is using this code to decrypt, `cipher.Init` should be called with `false`